# Rectangle Area Program: trouble accepting public static void main(String[] args);

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that returns the area of a rectangle after the user inputs a length and width. Java keeps finding an error in the line:

```
public static void main(String[] args);
```

It says "missing method body or declare abstract," but when i delete the semicolon at the end, it says "';' expected". What's wrong? Here is the rest of the code. There are probably other errors. Thanks.

```
public class Rectangle {  
public static void main(String[] args)
private static double length;
private static double width;

public Rectangle()
{
length = 1;
width = 1;
}
public Rectangle(double g, double w)
{
length = g;
width = w;
}
public double FindArea()
{
double area;
area = length*width;
return area;
}
}
```

Comment: That method needs a body.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the findArea to getArea to be more precise and just add a call to your main:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(2,3);
        System.out.println(rect.getArea());
    }
    private static double length;
    private static double width;

    public Rectangle()
    {
        length = 1;
        width = 1;
    }

    public Rectangle(double g, double w)
    {
        length = g;
        width = w;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        double area;
        area = length * width;
        return area;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the method body. This,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
private static double length;
private static double width;
```

should be something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello, World!"); // <-- replace with what you want to do.
}
private double length; // <-- each rectangle needs it's own
private double width;
```

`static` fields apply to every (or no) instance. You want those fields in each instance of `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 2):

`public static void main(String[] args)` declares a method, but its body is missing.

What is supposed to do?

For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 3);
    System.out.println("Area: " + r.findArea());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to try like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  //some code here
}
private static double length;
private static double width;
```

ie, you need to provided a body to your `main` medthod.